# PHP, for <= not expected results with decimals

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, decimal

When I run this PHP (5.4.31, running on 32-bit windows xp) code I get the result I'd expect:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i = $i + 0.5)
    echo $i .' ';
```

But if I move the decimal point over as so:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i = $i + 0.05)
    echo $i .' ';
```

despite the `<=` clause, the loop quits at 0.95 instead of at 1.

I'm aware that there is an imprecise nature to floating point numbers, but this seems kind of extreme.

Comment: "but this seems kind of extreme" --- in what way? If you understand some numbers cannot be represented precisely, how adding imprecise numbers being imprecise surprises you? For simplicity, assume the actual value (see the "closest representable") for the `0.5` literal is `0.51`, now try to evaluate your code manually.

Comment: I suspect it is exactly the floating point precision problem you referred to.  For fun, try the exact same code in a different programming language (e.g. Javascript).  You may find the exact same "incorrect" behavior for exactly the same reason.

Comment: @zerkms Perhaps I'm doing it wrong but when I try the code in my chrome javascript console, it stops before getting to 100 and I can see the imprecision kicking in, as noted in my answer below.

Comment: @adfaklsdjf I need glasses, I incremented it by `0.5`. When I spotted the mistake and tried with `0.05` it surely became reproducible, sorry.

Comment: In addition to the language constraints, you're also running it on 32-bit Windows XP, so it's likely using the old x87 instruction set, rather than the new one in modern processors. That would also attribute to the calculation error.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I realized there was another simple solution, using `round()`:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i = round($i + 0.05,2) )
    echo $i .' ';
```

The other answers are better though.  Thanks!  I should just have read the PHP manual page about floats.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with how floating point numbers are represented. To deal with this I would suggest changing your code to use integer indexes so,

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i = $i + 5)
    echo ($i/100) .' ';
```

That way you are just scaling the indexes up by a factor of 100 then dividing `i` by 100 inside the loop to get the float numbers you want.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this is floating point precision issues like you implied in your question.

For example, try the following javascript:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i = $i + 0.5) { console.log($i + " "); }
```

vs

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i = $i + 0.05) { console.log($i + " "); }
```

You will see the same behavior, and you will see the floating point imprecision rearing its head:

```
0 
VM4901:1 0.05 
VM4901:1 0.1 
VM4901:1 0.15000000000000002 
VM4901:1 0.2 
VM4901:1 0.25 
VM4901:1 0.3 
VM4901:1 0.35 
VM4901:1 0.39999999999999997 
VM4901:1 0.44999999999999996 
VM4901:1 0.49999999999999994 
VM4901:1 0.5499999999999999 
VM4901:1 0.6 
VM4901:1 0.65 
VM4901:1 0.7000000000000001 
VM4901:1 0.7500000000000001 
VM4901:1 0.8000000000000002 
VM4901:1 0.8500000000000002 
VM4901:1 0.9000000000000002 
VM4901:1 0.9500000000000003
```

If you need to iterate accurately over floating point like that, perhaps consider multiplying, rounding, and converting to integer while doing the iteration.

Comment: I did a data migration from a homebrew shopping cart system to an off-the-shelf system using Stripe as a payment gateway. The homebrew system used floating point for dollar amounts. The off-the-shelf system and Stripe's API used integer cents. I discovered while migrating data that sometimes I had an off-by-1-cent issue. I pulled my hair out for a short while, then realized it was floating point imprecision. There was a particular number that kept causing problems.. something like $1.13 or $13.30.. I can't remember and I don't want to.

Comment: That's interesting.  I wouldn't have thought to use a separate int value for cents.  Good to know that's something to be aware of.

Comment: Two integers, one for dollars and one for cents, would work.. but both the shopping cart system and Stripe's API used one integer.  E.g. an amount of $53.25 would be represented as 5325.  That's what I meant by "integer cents": five-thousand three-hundred and twenty five cents.

Comment: Gotcha!  Well if you run into that problem again you could just process that total cent integer value as a string in order to get your dollar decimal value: `$dollars_dot_cents = substr_replace($cents,'.',-2,-2);`  Should be foolproof.

Comment: Not sure why this answer was downvoted.. a comment as to why would have been nice...